# Update Half Of Table Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of 65,957 rows containing a processed flag column which are all set to 0. I am trying to take half of the rows and change that processed flag column to 5.

Table structure:

```
person, username, idnumber, code, value, time, processed
```

A person can be in the table multiple times.

Comment: Why mention that a person can be in the table multiple times? Is there some type of logic that needs to be added to this update?

Comment: @SadlyFullStack just half. Doesn't matter which way it is done.

Comment: MS Sql or MySql ?

Comment: please edit the question and show sample data and tag with RDBMS platform

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `WHERE id IN (subquery)`, you can filter in a common table expression, then update the filtered set directly.

```
WITH
  sample AS
(
  SELECT TOP 50 PERCENT * FROM table WHERE processed = 0
)
UPDATE
  sample
SET
  processed = 5
```

Example: https://dbfiddle.uk/7N4CAzGS

Comment: With this I am confused on what updating "sample" would do for me? I need table updated

Comment: @user19353552 `sample` essentially *is* the table, just with some rows filtered. It's like an updatable view.

Comment: @Charlieface so if I run that query then do SELECT * FROM table I will see half of them with 5 and half with 0?

Comment: Yes. Have you tried it? This should work fine. Note that `TOP 50 PERCENT` may not be perfectly accurate, eg if you have an odd number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
update <YourTable>
set processed=5
where id 
IN
(
Statements below with ID column
)
```

**To get the first 50% records:**

```
select top 50 percent * from <YOURTABLE>;
```

**To get the last 50% records:**

```
SELECT ID FROM
(SELECT top 50 percent * FROM <YOURTABLE> ORDER BY ID DESC)
ORDER BY ID;
```

Comment: not sure if the id is person or idnumber just use one of them on the statements above.

Comment: Going back can't I just do this?

UPDATE table SET processed = 5 
WHERE processed IN (SELECT TOP 50 PERCENT * FROM table WHERE processed = 0)

Comment: that will refine your query and might not affect the half of the rows and that was pointed on the question. but if you want to reduce the update time you can use the statement on your comment